# Is there any shortcut key to SELECT ALL text of Terminal?

Tags: 14.04

I am using Ubuntu 14 (with UI) and I was trying to find a shortcut key to SELECT ALL text in the Terminal

Currently I have to click on `EDIT > SELECT ALL` and this bothers me a lot :P